# Hide/show div inside div ? Typical one

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

My code :

```
    <div id="myDataTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">

    <div class="DTTT_container ui-buttonset ui-buttonset-multi" style="position: relative;">

    <button class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_copy ui-button ui-state-default"id="ToolTables_myDataTable_0">
    <span>Copy</span></button>
    <button class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_csv ui-button ui-state-default" id="ToolTables_myDataTable_1">
<span>CSV</span></button>
    <button class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_xls ui-button ui-state-default" id="ToolTables_myDataTable_2">
<span>Excel</span></button>
    <button class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_pdf ui-button ui-state-default" id="ToolTables_myDataTable_3">
<span>PDF</span></button>
    <button class="DTTT_button DTTT_button_print ui-button ui-statedefault"id="ToolTables_myDataTable_4">
<span>Print</span></button>  
    </div>
//here all my datatable html code comes .....
    </div>
```

I got this code from Google chrome inspect element. Above you can find parent DIV with id where as under that other DIV present with no id. 
I am amateur in jquery and i am planning to hide the child DIV inside the main DIV just for simple requirement to make it visible when i click on some button blah blah i can work on it?

How to hide it ?

```css
#myDataTable_wrapper // but i want child div which have no ID whatsoever 
{
display:none;
}
```

EDIT : 
Well after hiding the DIV present under Parent DIV .
When i call the Child DIV based on button click like below the entire DIV content hidden initially should come insde of a POPUP or under menu or in any other place not the previous location .

```
 $('#sss').click(function () {
            alert("ss");

$('#myDataTable_wrapper DTTT_container').dialog(//Hidden Div fetching logic inside should be written here  );
           //need to do something ,i am missing something
        });
```

Regards & sorry for making things complex to understand

Comment: you might be able to reference the div in question (looking at the structure of the html you provided) based on the class DTTT_container...  you can use a . instead of a # to signify a class instead of an id

Answer (score 2):

```css
#myDataTable_wrapper > div
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: One more query on same-thing after i make the hidden DIV visible using some jquery click function . can i make the hidden DIV to appear to somewhere under a menu button ?

Comment: don't forget to click solved when it fixed your problem :). Ask further questions in a different post :)

Comment: This will be trouble but my Hide is done but Show is not done . It will be cool for future reference for anyone everything at on place . Possible suggest me just how to make hidden DIV appear somewhere onclick ?

Answer (score 2):

You can take your div like this in javascript :

```
var divWithId = document.getElementById("myDataTable_wrapper");
```

And then you can take all div in the previous one like this :

```
var divs = divWithId.getElementsByTagname("div") //an array of div
```

In your case you hide/show your div like this :

```
function showHide()
{
    var divWithId = document.getElementById("myDataTable_wrapper");
    var divs = divWithId.getElementsByTagname("div") //an array of div
    var myDiv = divs[0];

    if(myDiv.style.display == "none")
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
    else
        myDiv.style.display = "none";

}
```

You call this function to change the state of your div. If the div is hiden, the function will shows it. If the div is shown, the function will hides it.

Comment: super fantastic . i like it

Comment: I have passed the last morning searching for it ^^

Comment: nice :) would you please check the second part of my question SHOW ? any suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. The function I have made simply switch between div shown/ div hiden. You can call it from every event you want.

Comment: yes you may be confused previously but once check it now given a brief intro to my need : edited

Comment: It can't be done that way. If you want you can play with the innerHTML propertie.

Comment: And I don't use JQuerry, only pure JS so I'm not sure to be the right person to answer you...

Comment: ooh actually the thing for this mess is when i use jquery datatable table tools plugin it will automatically create those above DIV under wrapper DIV . i have no control on it . so i am trying to explore ways to overcome the restrictions